# Is is possible to direct windows console output to a GUI?

Tags: java, ruby

I'm working on a project and I would like to execute programs in the windows console or a linux terminal.

Instead of launching a new console and working the program in it I want to do something like the following:

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k ruby rubycode.rb");
```

From this point on I want the user to be able to work with the program from the GUI/my program. The idea in my min is starting cmd in silent mode where it is not visible and latching on to it. Then redirecting the console output to the GUI and letting the user input data to the console through the GUI.

A similar concept is what most IDEs like jgrasp do. When you run a program you interface with it though their own command prompt.

How is this done? Iv'e tried grabbing the IOStreams from the process and trying to atleast print what the console outputs but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
public class ProcessTest {
private Process p;
private BufferedReader reader;
private BufferedWriter writer;

public void start() throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "dir");
    pb.directory(new File("./"));
    this.p = pb.start();
    this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.p.getInputStream()));
    this.writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.p.getOutputStream()));
    new Read(this.reader).start();
}

public boolean writeToConsole(String s) throws IOException {
    if (p == null)
        return false;
    this.writer.write(s + "\n");
    this.writer.flush();
    return true;
}

public class Read extends Thread {
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public Read(BufferedReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = this.reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new ProcessTest().start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

With the writeToConsole method you can write any string to the programm that you executed.

Comment: This is very nice and will definitely help me get started. I have a question about the process builder constructor. I've noticed that when I add more things to the String List such as: ("cmd", "/c","dir","dir"); the program will not function properly. Some commands never get executed. I will need to do several commands.

Comment: Also, when I get this to grab the process of a ruby script running in the console, it only prints the first line of the script when ends. Any use of the writeToConsole("string"); method results in true and no effect on the running script.

Comment: The pipe is being closed is the IOException I get when trying to write to the console when the line == null

Comment: Sure here it is http://pastebin.com/Tb32y3Dm
Off the bat: If that "dir" command isn't there, the ruby script never executes. When it does execute, it asks for a string, so I send in "bear face" the ruby script should then repeat the string.

Comment: [EDIT] if you uncomment this.writer.flush you will get the pip closed error

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Your help was instrumental and I thank you very much. The issue was changing /c to /k to keep the process running long enough to keep the pipe open and the process alive.